# I'm permanently the sole user of my machine, how can I make it so all files/folders/dirs ect. are set to me as the owner?

Tags: permissions, chown

Ubuntu 20.04. It's often that I get a message saying something like "you're not the owner of this file, unable to change". No one will ever be on my machine and I'd like it to recognize me as close to root as possible, yet safely. Is there a way to do so and how can I make my life a bit easier when it comes this sort of thing? I'm still a bit new with Linux but figured someone has a bit more knowledge with this.

Comment: Don't do it. It will break your system. Use sudo for that.

Comment: Sure thing. I figured as much, just thought someone had some useful tips/shortcuts to permissions and ownership. For instance, when I'm not in the terminal using sudo, i don't have permission to drag and drop a file into the trash bin.

Comment: The tip is not to change permissions on system files ;-)

Comment: Useful, ill do that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want that.

Files that belong to users other than the logged in user (belonging to root or an other system user, as e.g. the printer driver system, some database etc.) should not be touched (thrown to the trash bin) by that user.

If you unintentionally created a file as root, e.g. by starting a text editor with sudo and saving the file to your home directory, you can change that file to you as the owner and owning group by

```
sudo chown b1tchin:b1tchin filename.txt
```

(replace "b1tchin" by your username and "filename.txt" by the file name).

To change the owner of a whole directory to you, use the "-R" flag for "recursive":

```
sudo chown -R b1tchin:b1tchin folderName
```

As we said: DO NOT do this with any system folder (/usr, /root, /, /boot, /etc...), but ONLY with folders in your home directory or you WILL break your system.

By the way: sudo remembers your password for some minutes (15 I think is the standard). So to do some things using sudo root privileges, you can do that without a lot of extra typing.

Hope I could help

-- Streunekater